# Building Firebase Log in in Xcode

Tags: swift, firebase

I am doing a Log in from Firebase in XCocde and I can't get any further cause of a problem. How can I Fix the guard problem? cause he will alway show me a expert pattern

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func Button(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // get the default auth UI objekt
    }

    let authUI =  FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()

    let guard authUi != nil else {
        // log the error
        return
    }
}
```

I need to fix the guard authUi !=nil else {
return}

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem? you have to clearly state the issue, so I will assume you are looking for a print value of the error
    let authUI =  FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()

```
let guard authUi != nil else {
   print("error: \(String(describing: authUI?.localizedDescription))")
    return
}
```

Comment: yes I do I want to build a log in window with firebase but it does not work !

Comment: @DannyWolff what doesn't work? did my answer solve your problem?